# Angular Routing Params

Tags: html, angular, typescript, routes

I'd like to know if there is a way that the *parameters*, which a route possesses, will stay even if I **route/go** to another page?

For example:

`localhost:4200/welcomepage?param=true` => `localhost:4200/secondpage?param=true`

Answer (score 0):

Yes possible, you can try like this,

```js
import { ModuleWithProviders }  from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

/* Component */
import { welcomepage } from '../../modules/welcomepage/welcomepage.component';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'welcomepage/:param',
    component: welcomepage
  }
];

export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);

And in HTML page

<a [routerLink]="['/welcomepage', 'true']">Welcome</a>
```

and in HTML page,

Answer (score 0):

when navigating to another page, try as follows to pass the existing parameters

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute,
private router: Router) { }

const queryParams = Object.assign({}, this.route.snapshot.queryParams);
this.router.navigate(['./secondpage'], { queryParams: queryParams});
```